# Updating user post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

So I have a very basic form which allows users to edit their profile data:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
<div class="rh_contact_form">       
    <?php echo '<input type="text" id="rhc_phone" name="rhc_phone" placeholder="Phone number" value="' .$current_user -> billing_phone. '"/>' ;?>
    <?php echo '<input type="text" id="rhc_question" name="rhc_question" placeholder="My question" value="' .$current_user -> my_question. '"/>' ;?>
    <div class="rh_button">         
        <button type="button">
            <i class="icons">done</i>
        </button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Now, how do I implement `wp_update_user` in this case to update the user meta only if value is different from the current value or if it is not empty (for example, if they delete the current value in the input field, then it does not get rid of the meta).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer is You should implement a check like so :

```
if ( get_user_meta($user_id,  'some_meta_key', true ) != $new_value ){
// old data is different from new data 
}
```

Now, it has not been thoroughly tested by me , but I believe that you need to wrap it in a function and filter the `update_user_metadata` action like this :

First add the filter .

```
add_filter( 'update_user_metadata', 'pre_update_check_meta', 10, 5 );
```

Then the function

```
function pre_update_check_meta( $null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ) {

if ( 'some_meta_key' == $meta_key && empty( $meta_value ) ) {
        // Now check for NULL or EMPTY or compare with $old_value or whatever you want
        return true; // this means: stop saving the value into the database
    }

    return null; // this means: go on with the normal execution in meta.php

}
```

you just need to use the filters as described, and also add the `update_user_meta()` action to your action ( I believe you  called it `svf_send_message()` ) ..

Comment: Thank you the reply .  However I am not too familiar with how to use the function itself. Could you show me how to implement it in the code that I have on the question? I should be good after that. Thank you.

Comment: the code in OP is just a simple form, you did not specified where it is ( a plugin, in front-end, back-end ? ) and how it is submitted (ajax ? normal action ? ). the code i wrote is example for implementing the checks that you asked. if you do not know how to construct a form submission action maybe ask a new question or edit the original one.

Comment: Hi. thank you for the reply. I added the code which submits the form by the ajax. =)

Comment: Is the AJAX currently working ? where is the `cvf_send_message` function ??

Comment: Hi. The form works. I added the function in the question. I removed any sensitive information. But you will get the idea how the whole form is working. So, I am trying to figure out if I can update two fields (phone and "Ask" section) when the form is sent